# Determining as a function of n how often the statement incrementing the variable count is performed

Tags: java, algorithm, nested, nested-loops

Ok so I'm new to analyzing algorithms and would really appreciate any helpful tips that can be shared on how to go about this. I am trying to determine how many times count is incremented as a function of n. I have ran it in an ide and for values 1-7 the output is 1,3,6,10,15,21,28. Im just unsure how to write this as a function of n? Thanks.
The loop is as follows:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++){

    for (int j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++) {

         count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aim of this type of exercise is to teach how to you analyze it on paper instead of running  it on a machine. But let's look at the pattern:

- The outer loop will run a total of `n` times
- The inner loop will run between 1 to `n` times depend on what `i` is at the time. But you know that on average this will run `(n+1)/2` times.
- Thus `count = n(n+1)/2)`, which is `O(n^2)`

See [arithmetic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%C2%B7_%C2%B7_%C2%B7)

**Update:** As requested - why the inner loop is `(n+1)/2`:

The outer loop will increment i between 1 and n. So on each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will "loop" one more than than it did previously.

Thus the inner loop will iterate this number of times:

- 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n

So we can do something clever and pair up :

- n with 1: (n + 1) = n + 1
- n-1 with 2: (n - 1) + 2 = n + 1
- n-2 with 3: (n - 2) + 3 = n + 1
- ...

And since we paired these up, we have n/2 such pairs:

- So the sum of 1 + 2 + ... + n is ( (n+1) * (n/2) ).
- So the average is  ( (n+1) * (n/2) ) / n = (n+1)/2

(Visualize it as you are writing 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n on a long strip of paper, and you fold it in half.)

I would also highly recommend reading this [famous story about Karl Friedrich Gauss](http://www.jimloy.com/algebra/gauss.htm) so you'll always remember how to sum arithmetic series =)

Comment: If you don't mind, can you explain how you knew the inner loop is (n+1)/2? Thanks.

Comment: @user1840294 sure, see the updated answer and read the story in the link

Comment: @user1840294 - It is high-school maths.  (Indeed, I remember that we were expected to be able to **prove** this in high-school.)

Comment: @StephenC I will always remember learning about this with a primer on Karl Friedrich Gauss's 1 + ... + 100 story =)

Answer (score 1):

1

1+2 = 3

1+2+3 = 6

1+2+3+4 = 10

1+2+3+4+5 = 15

It is only me who sees the pattern? :-)

Comment: So what... you haven't actually answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

count = n * (n + 1) / 2