# How often an if-statement is executed?

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining as a function of n how often the statement incrementing the variable count is performed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483512/determining-as-a-function-of-n-how-often-the-statement-incrementing-the-variable)

Ok so I'm still new to analyzing algorithms and would appreciate any help that can be shared on this. I am trying to determine how often the if statement is executed as a function of n. I believe that the outer loop is n, and also think that the inner loop is n, but have trouble with the if statement. Any tips are appreciated, thanks.
 Here is the loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n.length;  k++) {

     for (int j = k; j > 0; j--) {

          if (n[j] < n[j-1]) {

            int x = n[j];
            n[j] = n[j-1];
            n[j-1] = x;
```

Comment: You mean how many times the code inside the `if` statement will execute? The `if` statement itself will execute every time you get to it.

Answer (score 4):

If I was doing this homework problem, I would start out with a few small arrays for n (so n.length is small), say 3 or 4, and then work through it by hand.  You'll see the pattern in no time.

Answer (score 1):

This example might help you

```
int[] n = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int count =  0;
for (int k = 0; k < n.length; k++) {
    for (int j = k; j > 0; j--) {
        count++; // if program reaches here, the below 'if' condition will be executed
        if (n[j] < n[j - 1]) {
            int x = n[j];
            n[j] = n[j - 1];
            n[j - 1] = x;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("If condition executed - "+count+" times.");
```

Comment: This is much better than working through it by hand as I suggested.  The real lesson is "Make the computer do the work for you" :)

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit of both answers above!

To get a clear number of calls, insert a counter and do some println/printf-Debugging (or use a logger).

To evolve an understanding of what's going on with these loops and to calculate the complexity it would be better to do manual iterations with low values of n.

You should follow both answers above to get a full understanding of your homeworks!